# Printing a linked list of integers in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to get an integer of any size to a linked list in C. But when I print the list, a zero is printed always after the the integer. 
Please note that I'm adding each digit of the integer to the head.(head has the 0th place of the integer)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int digit;
    struct node* next; 
};

void get_number(struct node** head);
int create_node(int digit, struct node** head);
void printlist(struct node* head);


int main()
{
    struct node* head1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));

    get_number(&head1);

    printlist(head1);

    return 0;   
}

int create_node(int digit, struct node** head)
{
    struct node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));

    tmp -> digit = digit;
    tmp -> next = *head;

    *head = tmp;

}

void printlist(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* curr = head; 
    if(!head)
        return;

    while(curr != NULL )
    {
        printf("%d",curr -> digit);
        curr  = curr -> next;
    }
}   

void get_number(struct node** head)
{
    int k;
    char c;

    c = getchar();
    while(c != '\n' && c != ' ')
    {
        k = c - '0';
        create_node(k, head);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

when I input 123456, the output is 1234560. 
I tried to find solution, but couldn't. Please help

Comment: `struct node* head1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));` --> `struct node* head1 = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` or `struct node* head1 = malloc(sizeof(*head1));` and `struct node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node*));` --> `struct node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` or `struct node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(tmp*));`

Comment: Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory!

Comment: forgot that too. Thanks

Comment: Also, `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char`... thus `c` should be declared `int c;` and your loop should look something like `while (c != EOF && c != '\n' && c != ' ') { ... }` (where `EOF` is an `int` value, of course, not a `char` value, so that test is meaningless if `c` is still a `char`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are one more node than necessary when you allocate to `head1`. You simply need to call the function `get_number()` as:

```
   struct node* head1 = 0;
   get_number(&head1);
```

which would set the `next` of the last element (i.e. the first allocate node) to `0` and rest of the logic would be fine.

You also need to correctly call `malloc()` and change the type of `c` to `int` (to handle `EOF`) as noted in the comments. My preferred way is to allocate memory is:

```
TYPE *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

Comment: Thanks! Allocating memory for head was wrong and it created a new node. That's the reason for the zero. Thanks for the other tips as well!